# Is it possible, in a line chart created with charts.js, to show the value at each dot within the chart itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Is it possible, in a line chart created with charts.js, to show the value at each dot within the chart itself?
Always, not just on mouse hover the dots.

I tried to include and use plugin datalabels but nothing appened and every similar question is referred to other types of chars.

```
var myNewChart=new Chart(ctx,{
        type:"line",
        data:data,
        options:{
            scales:{
                y:{
                    min:0,
                    ticks:{
                        callback:(label)=>`€ ${label}`
                    }
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'top',
                    formatter: function(value, context) {
                        return GetValueFormatted(value);
                    },
                    font: {
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.